# Gambas - How can I create radio (mutually exclusive) menu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, menu, gambas

I'm using [Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net) 2.13 on Ubuntu 9.10. I have created a QT graphical application and I'm trying to create radio (mutually exclusive) menu items, with a radio icon instead of a check mark when selected. I can't find any property in the Menu documentation that does that. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you mean an object that acts like a checkbox or radio button, but you want that in a menu.

If this is correct, then you want to edit yoru menu (ctrl + E)

Click on the menu item
Check the 'toggle' checkbox underneath the icon box

I have gambas2 2.25 and this works.